# Why am I getting "svn: command not found"

Tags: linux, bash, unix, svn

I'm wondering if anyone can help with figure out why my simple bash script is not working, I keep getting:

svn:command not found

even though I have svn installed and it works perfectly outside of my script.

```
#!/bin/bash

## Get Directory Path From User
printf "\n";
printf "Uses of ~/ or . To Designate Directory Structure Will Not Work!\n"
printf "\n";

printf "Please Enter The FULL Path To The Directory\n"
printf "Where We Shall Create Copy of Slides\n"
read PATH

## If Path Is Valid
if [ -d "$PATH" ]; then

    printf "Valid Path To Directory Entered\n"

    ## Attempt To Copy Files From SVN On Bluenose
    `svn checkout https://svn.cs.dal.ca/csci2132/all/slides/ $Path`

    printf "All Slides Have Been Copied To " 
    printf $PATH + "\n"
    printf "\n"

## Invalid Path Entered Tell User And Exit
else
    printf "Invalid Path Entered\n";
    printf "Please Try Again\n";
    exit 0;
fi

printf "Task Complete\n"
```

Comment: Your script reads PATH.  It looks for the command `svn` in PATH.  Pick a different name for the variable.

Comment: Is it safe to read user input into `$PATH`? Wouldn't that destroy the search path for binaries (such as `svn`)? Seems safer to choose a different variable name.

Comment: Also, you can get rid of the backquotes around the "svn" command :)

Comment: Also, I don't think you want backticks around that svn command, it'll send the output as a command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The shell looks through the colon separated list of directories in PATH to find executables.  Since you have used the name PATH to be the target destination, that is where it is looking for svn.  Just choose a different name for the variable.  That is, do not overwrite PATH.